# Sync Folders Between Home PC

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync

I have a Home PC with Windows 8 and a Work Laptop with Windows 8. I have several general folders in both the places that need to be sync.

**Example:**
Home PC (D:\Family Photo, E:\Home Videos, E:\Education Videos, E:\Tutorials\PFDs)
should get Synced both way
From Laptop (D:\Family Photo, D:\Videos\Home, D:\Videos\Education, D:\PDFs).

I know we can use SkyDrive or DropBox, but I think these Apps has below basic limitations which will not solve mapping for my own folders to get sync.
1) Need Internet 
2) We can select only ONE base Folder (Sub folders can be selective).

Please advise how we can achieve Sync between our folders?
Thanks.

Comment: I have also seen RichCopy(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) which is a great utility and may be I can have some script for this that will do the Copy as per my mapping. But not sure about if it can do 2 way (Sync).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Dropbox for online storage.
Limitation is indeed only to the dropbox-folder.

To sync folders and files outside of my dropbox folder I use
an addon for dropbox called Dropbox Folder Sync.

To sync between Home Pc and Laptop simply choose the same dropbox path which you can change in settings.

[image]

Really easy to use:

1. Run the Installer
2. To sync‘  a folder with Dropbox, right click it and click "Sync with Dropbox".
3. The first time you run the application it automatically sets the Dropbox Folder (Or 
   whenever the current Dropbox folder setting is corrupt)
   If this detection fails, it prompts you to enter the Dropbox path through interface.
4. For changing the Dropbox folder setting, go to Start Menu -> Programs -> Dropbox Folder
   Sync.
5. Unsync it, if you don’t need it anymore in Dropbox, by again right-clicking (at
   original path) and selecting “Unsync with Dropbox”.

More info about the software:
http://satyadeepk.in/dropbox-folder-sync/

Comment: Thanks for your input. The App looks very interesting and I will surely give this a try and see if that help.

Comment: I edited my awnser for usage in your situation. Using the same method myself and it works like a charm :)

Comment: SkyDrive would be better as it has more storage initially and offers the same features.

Comment: @pratnala SkyDrive offer more storage and has better Microsoft Office document integration, but also has the basic limitation of Sync to only one Base Folder. We cant Sync multiple folders (as my example).

Comment: With my solution it is possible to sync multiple folders.
Side-note: the size of all synced folders together is limited to the amount of storage you have available on dropbox.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't have this limitation? Neat!

Comment: The tool (Dropbox Folder Sync) doesn't have this limitation, indeed :). Dropbox itself doesn't give the option to sync folders different from the main dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

To sync folders outside of your SkyDrive, you need to create a Directory Junction.

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator.
   *Press the Start key.  Type "Command Prompt".  Right-click and choose "Run as administrator"*
2. Use `mklink /J` to create a link in your SkyDrive folder to the outside folder.

Example:

`mklink /J "C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\SkyDrive\My Home Videos Drive" "D:\Home Videos"`

Comment: Thanks Tim for your hint on SkyDrive as I will prefer native aplication doing multiple folder Sync, instead of installing add-on for the Sync Application. Can you please explain how these `Directory Junction` will work? Ex: If the Base SkyDrive folder is: `D:\MySkyDrive` and I want `E:\MyPics` to Sycn then I have to create a Directory Junction as your example and both the folders will get Sync? Can I have multiple Directory Junctions too? Any Limitations?

Comment: Adding another addition to my previous comment:  Even if we can add the Directory Junction, which will create a Pointer to the new folder that need to be Synced, then also how do we split or manage in target System where I need 2 folders instead of one.